# Model cart locking with Paypal

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal, shopping-cart, payment-processing

I'm currently implementing Paypal Express Checkout within a Zend Framework Application, I wrote my own cart model which consist of two simple class Cart & CartItem, and they are able to se quantity, get total price, etc.

I'm not much aware on payment system, and I only use Paypal (it's my first time), but I though since I'm not able to control what's happing there (at Paypal) it is a good idea to "lock" the Cart at the beginning of the process (when redirecting to Paypal) to avoid inconsistencies over the current Order processed by paypal and the actual cart on the website.

It can happen for example if the user open a new tab and try to add products while he is a payment process with paypal.

If your cart is locked the use is not able to add or remove anything from its cart until he finished to process the payment thorough paypal or cancel its order.

My question is do you think it is a good approach?

**Edit**: The reason I don't store anything in the database but only the shopping cart in session is all order are stored with Paypal, so I don't want to store it twice, it is a really really simple system.

Comment: I always add the cart to the DB as an order before sending it to any payment gateway and I empty their basket. Anything else they then add to the cart becomes a new order. If the payment is successful then I just change a flag on the order record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is fine. But make sure you inform the users why they can't add items to cart and offer an easy option to unlock the cart.

Use case:

- fill cart
- start payment
- ah, I forgot the socks
- close payment tab
- shop opened in other tab
- add socks
- "you can't add, it's locked"
- I can't return to payment to cancel it and can't add anything to cart => i leave

Comment: you're absolutly right, I though about this and I redirect the user to a friendly error page with the option to complete its payment or to cancel its current transaction and void it to avoid any further wrong payment

Answer (score 1):

I've done it a different way.

When the user browses the site, the cart is stored using a session, a cookie or whatever.

Once he clicks the "pay" button, the content of the cart goes to a `orders` datable table with a unique ID. 
You delete the session or the cookie to prevent him to add new stuff to the order.
You use the unique ID to give it to paypal. Once the payment is done, Paypal comes back to you with IPN, and gives you back the unique ID. From that you know it's paid and can put a boolean or something in your `orders` table.

Sometimes the user won't pay, and you'll have some never paid orders. You should have a cron that check orders older than one day and remove them from the table.